# Activate GCP windows server VM failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, activation

I created a windows 2012 server VM in GCP with 1 internal IP and 1 ephemeral external IP,
I can ping the the google KMS server 35.190.247.13,
but when I try activate the windows with

```
cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv
cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms 35.190.247.13:1688
cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```

the last step prompt error "The Software Licensing Service reported that the computer could not be activated. No Key Management Service (KMS) could be contacted. Please see the Application Event Log for additional information."

Do I need to enable google private access in my VPC subnet even though I have an external IP?

Comment: Your question needs more details. Does the VM have a public IP? Can you access the Internet from this VM? Are you using VPC Peering? Have you modified the VPC Firewall egress rules?

Answer (score 1):

`ping` is based upon ICMP, which is not associated with any transport layer (that's why it is impossible to `ping` a specific port). The command to test `tcp/1688` connectivity rather is:

```
powershell.exe Test-NetConnection 35.190.247.13 -Port 1688
```

If this doesn't work, you have to permit this destination in the firewall ruleset:

```
Address: 35.190.247.13
Port: 1688
Protocol: TCP
```

See [Windows Licensing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#licensing).

Comment: I tried run the command on my own laptop with internet access, but it also show pingSucceeded but TCPTestSucceeded=false. it's seems that the activation server is not running in the IP.

Comment: Obviously you need to run this command on the VM and it seems you haven't read the answer.